# Use ActiveRecord to count rows where id is matched and another column matches one of two values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I need to create a query in CodeIgniter as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `smslog_tbl`
WHERE (
       LOWER(ResponseStatus) = 'submitted'
       OR LOWER(ResponseStatus) = 'inqueue'
      )
      AND `SMSUsageID` = '1'
```

so I created a function in my model as:

```
function submittedSMSCount($smsUsageID) {        
    $this->db->where('lower(ResponseStatus)', 'submitted');
    $this->db->or_where('lower(ResponseStatus)', 'inqueue');
    $this->db->where('SMSUsageID', $smsUsageID);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('smslog_tbl');
}
```

but this function generates a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `smslog_tbl`
WHERE LOWER(ResponseStatus) = 'submitted'
      OR LOWER(ResponseStatus) = 'inqueue'
      AND `SMSUsageID` = '1'
```

These two queries generate different results because of the conditions. I need to group the **OR** conditions to get the correct result. How can I do this with CodeIgniter's Active Record query building methods?

Comment: It probably isn't the best approach here, because of course we want a clearly organized result, but you can always rewrite a boolean expression to get rid of ORs/ANDs to get a conjunctive/disjunctive normal form. You might try a Venn diagram to get an alternate view of how that works.

Comment: Please google my comments re 'googling phrasings' to help yourself in the future. This obviously is a very basic faq. And my first google, 'codeigniter sql parentheses "and" "or" in "where" ' hits tons of never-should-have-been-asked-or-answered duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function submittedSMSCount($smsUsageID) {       

$this->db->where(
       "(lower(ResponseStatus) = 'submitted' OR lower(ResponseStatus) = 'inqueue')", 
       NULL, 
       FALSE
 );  
$this->db->where('SMSUsageID', $smsUsageID);

return $this->db->count_all_results('smslog_tbl');

}
```

> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

**Ref :** https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 2):

use group with query builder

```
function submittedSMSCount($smsUsageID) {        
    $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS numrows')
    ->group_start()
    ->where('lower(ResponseStatus)', 'submitted')
    ->or_where('lower(ResponseStatus)','inqueue')
    ->group_end()
    ->where('SMSUsageID', $smsUsageID);
    return $this->db->get('smslog_tbl');
}
```

output

SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM `smslog_tbl` WHERE ( lower(ResponseStatus) = 'submitted' OR lower(ResponseStatus) = 'inqueue' ) AND `SMSUsageID` = '1'

Answer (score 1):

```
function submittedSMSCount($smsUsageID) { 
    $where = "(lower(ResponseStatus) = 'submitted' OR lower(ResponseStatus) = 'inqueue')";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->where('SMSUsageID', $smsUsageID);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('smslog_tbl');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to shoehorn an `OR` into your query, just use `IN()`.

Code:

```
public function submittedSMSCount(int $smsUsageID): int
{
    return $this->db->where_in('LOWER(ResponseStatus)', ['submitted', 'inqueue'])
                    ->where('SMSUsageID', $smsUsageID)
                    ->count_all_results('smslog_tbl');
}
```

This will result in `LOWER(ResponseStatus)` matching one of the two whitelisted values AND `SMSUsageID` will equal `$smsUsageID`.